# Best Audio Setting ffmpeg rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, ffmpeg

On my rails application I upload a video but unfortunately the audio quality when I read it is not good. I would like to know what are the best settings for the audio quality to be good.
Thank you.

```
PROCESSED_DEFAULTS = {
    resolution:           '500x400',
    video_codec:          'libx264',
    constant_rate_factor: '30',
    frame_rate:           '25',
    audio_codec:          'aac',
    audio_bitrate:        '64k',
    audio_sample_rate:    '44100',
    progress: :processing_progress
  }
```

Comment: Increase bitrate.

Comment: Try to use at least 128k or 256k in audio_bitrate